# sorting array of pairs on first value (date)

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array with pairs, where the first item in each pair is a date and the second an integer. I want to sort it on the dates and I'm stuck on how to do it.

example array

```
var dataTable = [[Fri Jun 13 2014 17:44:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time),4],[Tue May 27 2014 06:56:06 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time),4]]

dataTable.sort(function(a,b) { return  a[0]<b[0]});//How to sort the arraylist on the dates.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you missing quotes on your dates?

Comment: A start would be to write a small routine to parse the date strings to create Date objects, then compare those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: @anders, you better use RobG's code for consistency across all browsers, mark his answer as the selected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
     var dataTable = [
    ["Fri Jun 13 2014 17: 44: 25 GMT + 0200(W.Europe Daylight Time)", 4],
    ["Tue May 27 2014 06: 56: 06 GMT + 0200(W.Europe Daylight Time)", 4],
    ["Fri August 13 2014 17: 44: 25 GMT + 0200(W.Europe Daylight Time)", 4],
    ["Tue October 27 2014 06: 56: 06 GMT + 0200(W.Europe Daylight Time)", 4],
    ["Tue February 27 2014 06: 56: 06 GMT + 0200(W.Europe Daylight Time)", 4]
];


dataTable.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a[0]).getTime() - new Date(b[0]).getTime();
});
console.log(dataTable);
```

**[Check the Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qM6G8/2/)**

Comment: `sort` should return -1, 0, or 1 -- not a bool.

Comment: That sorts alphabetically. You need `new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0])` or something.

Comment: @ChakravarthySM—using [*Date.parse*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) to parse date strings is notoriously inconsistent between browsers, especially when non–standard strings are involved. And returning true or false from the compare function will not sort correctly, it is effectively only returning 0 or 1, never -1.

Comment: It is a consequence of using `new Date(string)`, see [*ECMAScript §15.9.3.2 new Date (value)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2)

Comment: If I use subs-tractor "-" also, it works, will it return -1 now

Comment: Yes, it does, provided Date.parse gets it right (and likely it won't in all implementations in use). When using the `-` operator, there is no need for *getTime*.

Comment: Yes, may be, anyway thanks for the Info, I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

You need a small function to convert the date strings to Date objects:

```
// Create a Date object from a date string in the format Tue May 27 2014 06:56:06
function parseDate(d) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var b = d.split(/[ :]/);
  return new Date(b[3], months[b[1].toLowerCase()], b[2], b[4], b[5], b[6]);
}
```

Then you can use date objects in the sort function:

```
var dataTable = [
  ['Fri Jun 13 2014 17:44:25 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)',4],
  ['Tue May 27 2014 06:56:06 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)',4]
];

dataTable.sort(function(a, b){
  return parseDate(a[0]) - parseDate(b[0])
});
```

Note that calling the Date function as a constructor with a string argument (see [ECMAScript §15.9.3.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2)) is the same as calling *Date.parse* and that parsing of date strings is largely implementation dependent and unreliable, even when using the format [*specified in ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) in browsers that support it.

Comment: A simple - return new Date(a[0]).getTime() > new Date(b[0]).getTime(); works, no need of conversion and all

Comment: The compare function used in [*Array.prototype.sort*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) should return 1, 0 or -1 depending on the result of the comparison. Using `<` will only return true or false, which will be type converted to 1 or 0 respectively. It will never return -1. See above for why `new Date(string)` is not appropriate.